# Track states in Corda vault

Tags: corda

I'm interested in tracking vault updates for states. Whenever a state of a specific contract state type, say `Token`, is produced or consumed in a transaction, I want to receive an update. I use the following query criteria

```kt
val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
    .and(
         QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(
             timeCondition = QueryCriteria.TimeCondition(
                 QueryCriteria.TimeInstantType.RECORDED,
                 ColumnPredicate.BinaryComparison(
                      BinaryComparisonOperator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL,
                      offset
                 )
             )
         )
    )
```

together with

```kt
ops.vaultTrackByWithSorting(
    TokenState::class.java,
    queryCriteria,
    Sort(
        setOf(
            Sort.SortColumn(
                SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.VaultStateAttribute.RECORDED_TIME),
                Sort.Direction.ASC
            ),
            Sort.SortColumn(
                SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.CommonStateAttribute.STATE_REF_INDEX),
                Sort.Direction.ASC
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Interestingly, I do see updates which produce `Token`s, but I do not see any updates when `Token`s get consumed. I'm using Corda 4.6.

I'm aware of the `_trackBy`'s limitations with respect to query criteria, however, according to Corda's vault api documentation, as I understand it, the above code should listen to both produced (`UNCONSUMED`) and consumed (`CONSUMED`) state updates. Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`VaultQueryCriteria()` sets `Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED` by default, if you don't specify it. So, in your case you are doing a query that logically does

```
(ALL).and(UNCONSUMED) = UNCONSUMED
```

The result is that you do not see the `CONSUMED`.

You need to specify the `StateStatus.ALL` also in your second query in `and()`.

I agree this is not clear in the documentation.

Comment: That's quite an unexpected behavior. Thanks for pointing that out! I find it still an issue, though. I'm interested in the observable for future `TokenState` updates (both consumed and unconsumed). Given the `Observable<Vault.Update<TokenState>>` I'm mapping over all of it's `produced` and `consumed` `StateAndRef`s, however, it seems that there are no `StateAndRef`s corresponding to `consumed` updates. Is that because the query criteria is not respected for future updates?